# How Can I Add Subscriber to MailChimp Sub Group

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I'm using the MailChimp api v2 to add subscribers to a list. The list has a single group with two subgroups. I cannot seem to add subscribers to the subgroups.

If I return the list information with:

```
$list = $MailChimp->call('lists/interest-groupings', array(
        'id' => '*OBSCURED*'
    )
```

I am returned an array with ids for the subgroups:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6425)
    ["name"]=>
    string(23) "OBSCURED"
    ["form_field"]=>
    string(6) "hidden"
    ["display_order"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["groups"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(23389)
        ["bit"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["name"]=>
        string(20) "OBSCURED"
        ["display_order"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["subscribers"]=>
        NULL
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(23393)
        ["bit"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["name"]=>
        string(21) "OBSCURED"
        ["display_order"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["subscribers"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, when I try to assign a subscriber to a subgroup with the id, I'm returned an error message:

> "23389" is not a valid Interest Grouping id for the list

The code I'm using:

```
$result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
            'id'                => 'OBSCURED',
            'email'             => array('email'=>$email),
            'merge_vars'        => array(
                                    'groupings' => array( 
                                        0 => array( 
                                            'id' => 23389,
                                            'groups' => array('OBSCURED')
                                            ) 
                                    )
            ),
            'double_optin'      => false,
            'update_existing'   => true,
            'replace_interests' => true,
            'send_welcome'      => true,
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

So, of course I figure it out right after posting the question. But, for anyone running into the same trouble here was the solution for me:

```
$result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
            'id'                => 'OBSCURED',
            'email'             => array('email'=>$email),
            'merge_vars'        => array(
                                    'groupings' => array( 
                                        0 => array( 
                                            'id' => 6425,
                                            'groups' => array(                                                    
                                                    'name' => 'OBSCURED',
                                            )                                                
                                        ) 
                                    )
            ),
            'double_optin'      => false,
            'update_existing'   => true,
            'replace_interests' => true,
            'send_welcome'      => true,
        ));
```

Basically I needed to nest the subgroup data within the top level group array.